# Android GoogleMobileAds not working in Real Device(Http response code:400)

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, admob

I am creating game in unity for android and integrated admob
but ads are not working on real device but Test ads are Working FINE in emulator and also in real Device but after Game Release there is not any ads so therefore I have checked logs that prints 
[image]

I am struggling on this issue from last 2 days. I have also tried many things as suggested on other posts but nothing helps .I have tried to change ad size to AdSize.SmartBanner .I have also updated sdk .also I have found some people says that google blocks some game from receiving ads but I have not received any mail about it.

**What is reason of this errors?**

Comment: have a look at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/Fn4kWHRJzf0

Comment: @Redman I already read it but doesn't  help

Comment: Have you given Admob Id correcly? try giving different admob app ID. Share code you have written